# Regex matching X, Y, Z, XY or XZ

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a converter that converts volumetric measurements of ingredients to grams.

This is my expression `/(\d?\u2009?\s?[\u00BC|\u2153|\u00BD|\u2154|\u00BE]?|\d?\u2009?\s?[1|2|3]\/[2|3|4]?)\s(cups|cup|teaspoons|teaspoon|tsps|tsp|tablespoons|tablespoon|tbsp|tbsps)?(.*)/g`

My issue is with the first group.

I want it to catch the amounts, all of these should be valid matches:

1
½
1/2
1½
1 ½
1 1/2

This `/\d?\u2009?\s?[\u00BC|\u2153|\u00BD|\u2154|\u00BE]?)/g` matches 1, ½, 1½ or 1 ½
This `/(\d?\u2009?\s?[1|2|3]\/[2|3|4]?)/g` matches 1, 1/2 and 1 1/2

`\u2009` is a character that is used on some cooking websites, the other unicodes are for all the fractions that are commonly used in recipes.

I don't know how to combine them or make an expression that would encompass all of them,

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You may need to swap the alternatives, `\d?\u2009?\s?[1|2|3]\/[2|3|4]?` must come before `\d?\u2009?\s?[\u00BC|\u2153|\u00BD|\u2154|\u00BE]?`. Certainly, you need to clean the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Good way to combine.
Verbose but  minimal backtrack.
Try

```
/(\d[\ ]*[ \t]*[¼⅓½⅔¾]|[¼⅓½⅔¾]|\d[\ ]*[ \t]*(?:1\/[432]|2\/3|3\/4)|(?:1\/[432]|2\/3|3\/4)|\d)(?!\S)(?:[ \t]+(cups|cup|teaspoons|teaspoon|tsps|tsp|tablespoons|tablespoon|tbsp|tbsps))?/
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/T4VLLl/1)